# SupportFragmentManager replace not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-support-library

**FIXED**

I outsourced the Bluetooth scanning to a separate thread which was a failure. :D Having fixed this the code now works. Thanks for all support!

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I'm having troubles with exchanging dynamically added fragments (I use the support library and my minimal API version is 8 (Android 2.2)). In my XML which can be seen below file I have a FrameLayout which contains the fragment.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".BluetoothConnectionManager">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/frmlFragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/tbBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/hafnertec"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/lblMode"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/lblMode"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
            <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btnRefresh"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/lblMode"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:longClickable="false"
                android:onClick="updateData"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</RelativeLayout>
```

For exchanging the fragments i use a SupportFragmentManager. Furthermore, I also instantiate the two fragments in the onCreate() method. In addition, the fragment for discovering Bluetooth devices is added to the frame layout which works fine.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ...
    // fetch a FragmentManager used for exchanging the fragments
    this.fmFragmentExchanger = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
    this.btDiscoveryFragment = new BluetoothDiscoveryFragment();
    this.btConnectorFragment = new BluetoothConnectorFragment();

    if (this.findViewById(R.id.frmlFragmentContainer) != null)
    {
        this.fmFragmentExchanger.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frmlFragmentContainer, this.btDiscoveryFragment).disallowAddToBackStack().commit();
    }
    ...
}
```

Moreover, I've taken care that the fragments extend the Fragment class provided by the support library:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
public class BluetoothDiscoveryFragment extends Fragment implements ...
{
    // see: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_connection_bluetooth_device, container, false);
    }
```

Here is my code for exchanging the fragments:

```
this.fmFragmentExchanger.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frmlFragmentContainer, this.btConnectorFragment).disallowAddToBackStack().commit();
```

The class for discovering Bluetooth devices makes use of a BroadcastReceiver which is "connected" with the activity. On stopping the discovery process or when it has finished I unregister this BroadcastReceiver.

However, on exchanging the fragments nothing happens and after some time I get an error caused by SIGABRT:

```
12-31 15:09:51.621    9790-9795/com.hafnertec.afdbluetooth I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
12-31 15:09:53.945    9790-9790/com.hafnertec.afdbluetooth A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000001bd (code=0), thread 9790 (ec.afdbluetooth)
```

Here you can see the file /data/anr/traces.txt: [trace file](https://copy.com/DWbrEjfgOaxoXUQK)

I'm running the tests on a Samsung Galaxy S I9000 with Android 4.4.4 (CM SNAPSHOT M12). During the activity's onCreate() method I add the btDiscoveryFragment instance which works fine:

```
this.fmFragmentExchanger.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frmlFragmentContainer, this.btDiscoveryFragment).disallowAddToBackStack().commit();
```

Furthermore, adding the instance btConnectorFragment using .add() works. However, it logically causes the btConnectorFragment to be overlayed over the btDiscoveryFragment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo, causing `btDiscoveryFragment` to be null:

```
this.fmFragmentExchanger = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
//add this line
this.btDiscoveryFragment = new BluetoothDiscoveryFragment();
//remove this duplicated line
//this.btConnectorFragment = new BluetoothConnectorFragment();
this.btConnectorFragment = new BluetoothConnectorFragment();
```

Comment: oh, it was just an error in your question? did you fix the code in your app too? ;)

Comment: In my application the code has been right regarding this error. I forgot to mention that I add the fragment btDiscoveryFragment during the activity's onCreate() method which works fine. I have updated my question.